# Shopify - Adding Email Form to Add-to-Cart Button

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

Is there a way to add some kind of form requesting the customer email address when adding to the cart?

1. click 'add to cart'
2. popup asking for email (optional)
3. moving forward to the cart, passing along the add to cart product info.

My understanding is that with forms, you have your `action` attribute which says where the form's data will be sent and that your button's `type` attribute of submit will execute the form's action.

I know each theme is different and some don't have a button element with `type="submit"` to execute the action.  But with a [theme like "Debut"](https://themes.shopify.com/themes/debut/styles/default/preview), which has a very simple add-to-cart form, how would you go about this?

Note:  I don't need help creating a lighbox, but I'm confused about how to refrain from executing the cart action until the popup is finished (meanign the customer has either entered their email or chosen to decline).

Please let me know if you need any more information!  Thanks

Comment: It is possible. I have done this earlier. Requires a good amount of work.

Comment: Any advice on making this happen?

Comment: Depends on what you're going to do with the email that you're collecting. Simple idea would be converting the input/submit to input/button and execute a script to display the box and then submit the form through javascript.

Comment: Thanks, that idea is what I was looking for :)